# Switching To the DetailView of a NavigationController?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

How can I get to the DetailView inside a NavigationController. The Navigation Controller is inside a TabBarController. I managed to display it, but then the NavigationBar and the TabBar disappear.

Screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0GN5.png

Answer (score 0):

You have one the following options:

1. Change the `FirstViewController` from `UIViewController` to `UINavigationController` and push `DetailView` into it.
2. Present `DetailView` as modalView
3. Programmatically, add view of `DetailView` to `FirstViewController` as subview

Hope it helps.